# Ignore all tests from specflow using [BeforeTestRun] hook

Tags: selenium, nunit, specflow

My project has 2 default configurations (Debug and Release) and a custom one called UITest.

When the UITest config is selected it changes ioc to use an in memory verson of my database which is perfect for my ui tests.

I am using NUnit and resharper to run my tests and would like to only run the ui tests when my UITest configuration is active.

I decided to go with the [BeforeTestRun] hook to achieve this but I cant get it to ignore the tests.

Throwing an exception will prevent all the tests from running but they show as a fail, i would prefer to have them show as pending or ignored. Is this possible?

```
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTests()
    {
    #if !UITest
        throw new Exception("abort!");
    #endif
    }
```

### Addendum

If I change it to this:

```
    [BeforeTestRun]
    public static void BeforeTests()
    {
    #if !UITest
        Assert.Ignore();
    #endif
    }
```

Then each of the scenarios will show as ignored but the feature will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `BeforeTestRun` hook is the method that runs only once, before the run starts. If you want to skip this whole testrun, you can use `Environment.Exit();` to exit the run.
In MSTest the tests will show up as not run, but I am not sure how NUnit or Resharper handles this.

Comment: `Environment.Exit(0);` will cause the test to show as inconclusive. This is an improvment to a fail. Many thanks.

Comment: @4imble Thank you for sharing, nice to know.